# how to resolve dynamically bean type in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have code something like this (please ignore syntax)

```
     Interface Fruit{
         color{};
    }

    class Mango extends Fruit{
Mango(String color){
sop(color)}
}

class Apple extends Fruit{
Apple(String color){
sop(color)}
}


    Class SomeClass{

    method(Fruit f){
    f.color()
    }

    }


    Class Caller {

    @Autowired
    public Fruit fruit;

    @Autowired 
    public SomeClass someClass;

      someClass.method(fruit);

    }
```

I have two fruits (Apple and Mango), I want to write configuration in such a way that i can pass different fruit dynamically.

```
<bean id=mango class = Fruit>
  <constructor-arg value="yellow"/>

  <bean id=apple class = Fruit>
  <constructor-arg value="red"/>
```

And that particular fruit color method called.
Please let me know how should i write remaining configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know if it answer exactly your question but i used to do it like this :

```
<bean class="yourpathtoyourclassCaller">
    <property name="fruit">
      <bean id=apple class = Fruit>
      <constructor-arg value="red"/>
      </bean
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for sure:

Use factory bean/ factory method.. etc, check it out here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

```
<bean id="apple" class="FruitFactory"
    factory-method="fruitFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="red" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongo" class="FruitFactory"
    factory-method="fruitFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="yellow" />
</bean>

public class FruitFactory {

    public static Fruit fruitFactory(String color) 
    {
        if ("red".equals(color)) 
        {
            return new Apple();
        }
        else if ("yellow".equals(color))
        {
            return new Mongo();
        }

        //
    }
}
```